# merge extra rows being added R

Tags: r, merge

I have two very large dfs (x= 379638 rows and y[routes] = 4103141  rows). I want to merge y into x, and I do this using every common variable between the two dfs. However, despite me using all the variables I can, my merge code is still adding on an extra 5000 rows (merged df =  384586 rows). My code is the default all.x=FALSE.... so unsure of whats happening here, given that I'm using every variable in each df to merge on. Does anyone know what I'm doing incorrectly?

Below are two mini-samples from my two dfs, (just copy and paste into your console to see) plus my code.

```
df<-merge(x,routes, by=c('hai_dispense_number', 'hai_age', 'sex', 'date_of_claim', 'quantity', 'hai_ddd', 'hai_strength', 'eligibility_end_date', 'hai_atc'))
```

First df (x)

```
x<- read.table(header=T, text=" hai_dispense_number sex hai_age eligibility_end_date quantity date_of_claim hai_atc hai_strength hai_ddd
13   PatientHAI0000092   F      42           2011-02-28        9    2010-06-16 N05BA01         2.00    10.0
14   PatientHAI0000092   F      42           2011-02-28        3    2010-06-16 N05CF02         5.00    10.0
41   PatientHAI0000110   F      31           2011-07-31       10    2010-09-09 N05BA12       250.00     1.0
72   PatientHAI0000360   F      58           2014-10-31       30    2010-04-21 N05CF02        10.00    10.0
82   PatientHAI0000360   F      58           2014-10-31       30    2010-07-19 N05CF02        10.00    10.0
111  PatientHAI0000522   M      38           2012-08-31       10    2010-07-06 N05CF01         7.50     7.5
134  PatientHAI0000731   F      28           2010-12-29        7    2010-06-15 N05CF01         7.50     7.5
137  PatientHAI0000731   F      28           2010-12-29       15    2010-08-18 N05BA12       500.00     1.0
139  PatientHAI0000731   F      29           2012-02-12       42    2010-09-10 N05BA12         0.25     1.0
159  PatientHAI0000798   F      41           2011-08-31       14    2010-06-30 N05CF01         7.50     7.5
")
```

second df (routes)

```
routes<- read.table(header=T, text="hai_dispense_number sex hai_age quantity date_of_claim hai_atc hai_roa hai_strength hai_ddd eligibility_end_date
1   PatientHAI0217603   F      75       14    2010-04-16 N05BA12     O           0.25    1.00           2016-04-30
2   PatientHAI1614296   F      74       30    2010-04-28 N05CD06     O           1.00    1.00           2015-11-30
3   PatientHAI0408690   F      91       28    2010-04-15 N05BA12     O           0.25    1.00           2013-06-30
4   PatientHAI0050917   M      67       56    2010-04-15 N05BE01     O          10.00   30.00           2020-12-31
5   PatientHAI0143945   M      64       30    2010-04-14 N05BA01     O           5.00   10.00           2010-07-31
8   PatientHAI2149890   M      72       84    2010-04-27 N05BA08     O           1.50   10.00           2011-06-30
10  PatientHAI1903034   F      80       45    2010-04-01 N05CD07     O          20.00   20.00           2020-12-31
11  PatientHAI0205229   F      80       56    2010-04-22 N05CD07     O          20.00   20.00           2020-12-31
13  PatientHAI0317751   F      71       30    2010-04-26 N05CD05     O           0.25    0.25           2016-11-30
14  PatientHAI1986979   M      22       15    2010-04-19 N05BA01     O          10.00   10.00           2012-11-30
")
```

additional information regarding duplicates:

in x some duplicates naturally exist - this is ok - and I need to keep these. e.g., see last two rows below

```
natural_dups<- read.table(header=T, text="  hai_dispense_number sex hai_age eligibility_end_date quantity date_of_claim hai_atc hai_strength hai_ddd
1597868  Patient HAI0002446   F      82           2011-08-31       42    2010-08-25 N05BA01            2      10
5495829  Patient HAI0002446   F      83           2011-08-31       30    2010-11-25 N05BA01            2      10
5580466  Patient HAI0002446   F      83           2011-08-31       30    2010-11-05 N05BA01            2      10
5686765  Patient HAI0002446   F      83           2011-08-31       30    2010-12-22 N05BA01            2      10
6146708  Patient HAI0002446   F      83           2011-08-31       30    2011-02-23 N05BA01            2      10
6351254  Patient HAI0002446   F      83           2013-05-31       28    2011-03-23 N05BA01            2      10
6686613  Patient HAI0002446   F      83           2013-05-31       28    2011-05-20 N05BA01            2      10
6686620  Patient HAI0002446   F      83           2013-05-31       28    2011-05-20 N05BA01            2      10
")
```

however, after the merge, an extra THIRD row has been added here

```
merged_dups<- read.table(header=T, text=" hai_dispense_number hai_age sex date_of_claim quantity hai_ddd hai_strength eligibility_end_date hai_atc hai_roa
184  Patient HAI0002446      83   F    2011-05-20       28      10            2           2013-05-31 N05BA01     O  
185  Patient HAI0002446      83   F    2011-05-20       28      10            2           2013-05-31 N05BA01     O  
186  Patient HAI0002446      83   F    2011-05-20       28      10            2           2013-05-31 N05BA01     O  
")
```

Comment: It is very nice that you have given examples of the data sets which can be directly pasted into R. However, with these data sets your problem is not reproducible because none of the records in the data sets match. Without an repreducible example  we can only guess.

Comment: My guess is that you have both duplicates (on the merge keys) in `x` and `y`. This will generate all combinations of those records, e.g. see `merge(data.frame(a=c(1,1)), data.frame(a=c(1,1,1)))`

Comment: @JanvanderLaan - nuts, sorry about about samples, I should have spotted that. Regarding your explanation about dups in both x and y, I think you're right. Thank you. :)

Comment: Try using `join` in the `plyr` package. It usually gives much more intuitive results.